# Mocking REST Client

Tags: spring-boot, rest, mocking

I use the following test to test my API Endpoint in my Spring-Boot App:

```
    public void getFreeProducts200() throws Exception {
        final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/events/528409/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        final ResultActions mvcResponse = this.mvc.perform(request);
        mvcResponse.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
    }
```

The path /api/v1/events/{0}/ is mapped to a method that calls another REST service.
I want to mock this underlying REST interface. How can I do that?